# Correlation between http request and response using OpenTelemery

Tags: .net, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

How can I correlate http request and response using Opentelemetry / Opentelemetry Collector. What parameters we need to correlate.Can you suggest some good example or POC's that I can refer preferably in .Net/C#

I want to establish Correlation between http request and response using OpenTelemery

Answer (score 0):

I'll make some assumptions here since your question is a bit vague. If we are talking about an AspNetCore API that receives a request from the outside, then makes a request to another service (say, using `HttpClient`), then you can achieve proper distributed tracing by adding both AspNetCore and Http instrumentations to your project.

For a modern project, I'd recommend starting with this package:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting

It makes it easier to add instrumentations/exporters/resource detectors when using dependency injection and the standard Web API project startup with `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` classes.

With this, you should add these 3 extra packages:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore
  This adds the main tracing instrumentation to AspNetCore, which will ensure a root trace is created if no trace information is provided with each request, or a child trace in case external trace info is passed in
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Http
  This adds instrumentation to all calls made through the `HttpClient` class in the entire process. This is what will ensure that the trace context from the main request is propagated to calls made outside of the API to other services
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenTelemetry.Exporter.OpenTelemetryProtocol
  This is the exporter package, which will push all telemetry data generated by the instrumentations into your OTEL collector.

Configuration for a simple scenario would look something like this:

```cs
services.AddOpenTelemetry()
    .WithTracing(c => c
        .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
        .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
        .AddOtlpExporter())

    .WithMetrics(c => c
        .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
        .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
        .AddOtlpExporter());
```

Assuming you configure the exporter URL to point to your collector, this should give you basic http+aspnetcore distributed tracing.

If you have other stacks in your API, such as WCF/SOAP services, direct SQL database calls, EntityFrameworkCore integration, etc, you should consider including the instrumentation packages for those stacks, which will then enhance your traces further with specific spans for each integration.